# RegEX: How to exclude between string and to match the renaming string

Tags: python, regex

I did make the inverse, match between two string and exclude the remaining, but I'm not getting deny the first sentence.

String:

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.11.19 = Hex-STRING: 14 CC 20 B7 F5 D1 70 4F 57 4C D3 95
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.12.21 = Hex-STRING: 18 A6 F7 80 27 6F C4 E9 84 A8 B9 B1 18 A6 F7 80
32 B3
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.13.22 = Hex-STRING: 30 B5 C2 CE 55 81 C4 E9 84 BD 58 E5
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.16.25 = Hex-STRING: 18 A6 F7 65 A5 75 C4 E9 84 CB CC 61 B0 4E 26 8B
4E E5 B0 4E 26 8B 41 E7 84 16 F9 92 EA CB C4 E9
84 A8 C1 3D
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.17.29 = Hex-STRING: 70 4F 57 4C CB FF 70 4F 57 39 5E 33
iso.3.6.1.4.1.25355.3.2.6.4.2.5.1.7.3.2.18.38 = Hex-STRING: 98 DE D0 D3 4E 7D 18 A6 F7 80 3D 41 84 16 F9 AF
E2 AF 9C 6F 52 12 08 A7
```

RegEX: `(?=iso)(.*)(?<=:)`

Result: Matching `iso... STRING:`. I would like to match all hexadecimal address.

Comment: What should the result look like for the above sample string? A list of lists like `[[3, 6, 1...], [3, 6, 1, 4, 1,...]]`?

Comment: These Hex are MAC address, would be good to separate of six two-digit. Like 
[[ 70 4F 57 4C CB FF], [70 4F 57 4C CB F3] ..]

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52616083/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

s = "YOUR_DATA"
results = []
for match in re.findall(r'Hex-STRING:(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+', s):
    results.append([" ".join(x.split()) for x in re.findall(r'[\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5}', match)])
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['14 CC 20 B7 F5 D1', '70 4F 57 4C D3 95'], ['18 A6 F7 80 27 6F', 'C4 E9 84 A8 B9 B1', '18 A6 F7 80 32 B3'], ['30 B5 C2 CE 55 81', 'C4 E9 84 BD 58 E5'], ['18 A6 F7 65 A5 75', 'C4 E9 84 CB CC 61', 'B0 4E 26 8B 4E E5', 'B0 4E 26 8B 41 E7', '84 16 F9 92 EA CB', 'C4 E9 84 A8 C1 3D'], ['70 4F 57 4C CB FF', '70 4F 57 39 5E 33'], ['98 DE D0 D3 4E 7D', '18 A6 F7 80 3D 41', '84 16 F9 AF E2 AF', '9C 6F 52 12 08 A7']]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/nWfHkw).

The [`Hex-STRING:(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2})+`](https://regex101.com/r/Q1IO3p/1) pattern will match `Hex-STRING:` and then 1 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and then 2 hex chars, as many times as possible. These matches will serve as input for the second regex, `[\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5}`, that will extract all the expected results from those pre-extracted strings.

The `[\dA-Fa-f]{2}(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5}` pattern matches two hex chars with `[\dA-Fa-f]{2}` and `(?:\s+[\dA-Fa-f]{2}){5}` matches five consecutive occurrences of 1+ whitespaces followed with two hex chars.

The `[" ".join(x.split()) for x in re.findall(...)]` list  comprehension helps replace line breaks between hex pairs with a single space.

Comment: I was reviewing the pattern and found something strange, if you run the python demo, you'll see that some hexadecimals does not get matched with the pattern. That's the problem that is occurring with me.

Comment: @TMoraes Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to match the hex values at the end of each line, something like this should be sufficient:

`Hex-STRING:\s*(.*)$`

This will match `Hex-STRING` followed by any whitespace, and then capture everything until the end of the line.

Here's an example using your provided input: https://regex101.com/r/1TKKcf/2